# Como puedo borrar las options que ya se tildaron de un select con jQuery o JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, formularios, label

Quiero que una vez que se seleccione por ejemplo el horario de las 09:00, la proxima vez que se recarge la pagina y se vuelva a completar el formulario el horario de las 09:00 ya no aparezca. Como puedo lograr esto con jQuery o JS.

```
<label class="mb-2" for="hora">Hora</label>
          <select id="hora" name="Hora del turno" class="form-control mb-2" required>
            <option disabled selected> Seleccione hora </option>
            <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
            <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
            <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
            <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
            <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
            <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
            <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
            <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
          </select>
```

Comment: Que tal Gatitq, bienvenido a SO en Español... te recomiendo que vayas a [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio y luego a [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas, de esta y de otras en el futuro... Respecto a tu pregunta actual, ¿En que contexto estas aplicando esto? danos mas información acerca de la situación de tu trabajo. darte una opción hecha en javascript o jquery tal vez pueda responder tu pregunta pero no se adapte a lo que tu necesitas

Comment: Para esto necesitas un backend y, a mi manera de ver, una pregunta así es demasiado amplia para el formato del sitio. Hay cientos de opciones para backend, si combinas plataformas, lenguajes, bases de datos. Si no tienes idea, es mejor que investigues, comiences a hacerlo en la plataforma de tu elección y vuelvas acá si se te presenta alguna dificultad.

Comment: Podrías usar [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) para lograr permanencia de datos en tú página.

Answer (score 0):

La manera más simple para hacer esto es usando los **localStorage**, te voy a poner como un ejemplo html que está más o menos adaptado al que muestras:

```
<html>

    <head>
    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <form action="./" method="post">
            <select id="hora" name="Hora del turno" class="form-control mb-2" required>
                <option disabled selected> Seleccione hora </option>
                <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
                <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
                <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
                <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
                <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
                <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Como JS + JQuery:

```
$(function(){

        //Prevencion del submit al form:
        
        $("form").submit(function(et){
            
            et.preventDefault();
            et.stopPropagation();
            
        });
        
        let element2 = $("#hora").next("input");
        
        $(element2).click(function(et){
            
            
            if( $("#hora").val()){ //Tiene que tener un valor.
                
                if(localStorage.getItem('horarios') === null){
            
                    localStorage.setItem('horarios', $("#hora").val() + ', ');
                }else{
                
                    let horariosx = localStorage.getItem('horarios');
                    
                    
                    let comprobarDuplicados = horariosx.split(", ");

                    //Tener tambien en cuenta que el elemento que queramos añadir, no este en el array.
                    
                    
                    if(comprobarDuplicados.indexOf($("#hora").val()) == -1){
                        
                        horariosx += $("#hora").val() + ', ';
                    
                        localStorage.setItem('horarios', horariosx);
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        
        });





    //Lo primero es hacer uso de localStorage, si no esta guardado, retornará nulo.

    let horarios = null;

    //En el caso de las pruebas, para eliminar usa localStorage.removeItem("horarios");
    
    if(localStorage.getItem('horarios') === null){
        
        localStorage.setItem('horarios', ', ');
    }else{

        horarios = localStorage.getItem('horarios');
        
        //Al no ser nulo le hacemos un split
        
        horarios === ', ' ? horarios = new Array() : horarios = horarios.split(', ');
        
        //Mal planteamiento que tuve, era el de iterar sobre todos los elementos del array horarios, prefiero usar el indexOf
        
        $("#hora option[value]").each(function(index, element2){
        
            if(horarios.indexOf($(element2).attr("value")) != -1){
                
                //Si esta en el array de los horarios pues lo eliminas.
                
                $(element2).remove();
                
            }
        });
    }

});
```